# Rails gon with jbuilder not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, jbuilder

Rails 5 app using gon 6.2.0 and jbuilder 2.7.0

My issue is in production mode, but in development everithing works fine my production log:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - app/views/productos/index.json.jbuilder):
```

F, [2018-01-26T21:03:03.809472 #7851] FATAL....

but the file exist (in dev mode it works fine) and the logs continue with the next:

```
app/controllers/productos_controller.rb:19:in `index'
```

and in my controller in line 19 i have this:

```
def index

@productos = @negocio.productos.where(activo: true).order(:codigo)
gon.jbuilder  //this is line 19
respond_to do |format|
```

so there is the problem.  why it is not working or finding the file in production mode?? but it works perfect in dev?
thanks

Comment: can you re-check if file exists in production environment

Comment: @Sharj the issue was because i leave server running in backgroud with this command: rails server -e production -d &. Now I am runngin in foreground rails server -e production and it works fine. How can i leave the server running in bg?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, can't daemonize the app because `gon.jbuilder` start looking on the system root folder. Did you find a solution?